# Usage of stubs from OpenAPI generator

Tags: erlang, swagger, openapi

I am trying to build my own REST API using Erlang. I am following the guide which can be found at:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/samples/server/petstore/erlang-server.

Now I am currently stuck at the last point: after running from the Erlang shell `application:ensure_all_started(http_server).` I think the application is running, since from `netstat -nlt | grep LISTEN` I can see the process listening on `127.0.0.1:8080`.
If for example I try to run:

`curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/pet/44362" -H "accept: application/json"`

I obtain no response from the server, and on the server I only see `Attempt to process operation: GetPetById"` and nothing else happens. I think it is supposed to return a 404 error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you are missing is the `-i` flag to `curl`. `curl` doesn't print the http response code if you don't tell it to.

```
$ curl -i -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/pet/44362" -H "accept: application/json"
```

Will show that the server actually responds with http code `401` (Unauthorized), looking at the OpenAPI schema for `GetPetById` (the `operationId` for the endpoint you are trying) we can see it requires an api key as a header named `api_key` in the http request (see the `securityDefinitions` section in the OpenAPI schema). So the real `curl` command we need is

```
curl -i -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/pet/2342" -H "api_key: asdf" -H "accept: application/json"
```

(you can use any value for the `api_key`)

However, this won't give the answer you expected (response code `404`), instead you'll get a `501` (Not Implemented).
This is because the openapi generator tool only generates the scaffolding needed for you to build the actual logic for each endpoint handler. The generator tool has no way of knowing how you want to handle the incoming requests, so it generates a generic handler that returns the `501` response.

Look in the `openapi_default_logic_handler.erl` file, there you will find `handle_request/3` which is the request handler.
A minimal change to handle the `GetPetById` endpoint would be:

```erlang
handle_request('GetPetById', _Req, _Context) ->
  % This is a hardcoded 404 response for all id's.
  % add your logic here to e.g try to fetch the id from a database 
  {404, #{}, #{}};
handle_request(OperationID, Req, Context) ->
    error_logger:error_msg(
        "Got not implemented request to process: ~p~n",
        [{OperationID, Req, Context}]
    ),
    {501, #{}, #{}}.
```

Also note that in the file `openapi_default_logic_handler.erl` the function `authorize_api_key/2`is defined. That's where you can implement validation of the `api_key` header value, by default it allows any value.